# register_activation_hook with include file

Tags: plugins, activation

I'm yanking my hair out with the following code, please help.
I have 3 files.

File1.php:

```
Class File1 {
    public function file1_register() {
        //register some short codes;
    }
    public function file1_unregister() {
        //unregister previous short codes;
    }
}
```

File2.php:

```
Class File2 {
    public function file2_register() {
        //create some database tables.
    }
    public function file1_unregister() {
        //delete previous tables.
    }
}
```

MyPlugin.php:

```
function MyActivation() {
    include_once (dirname(FILE).'/file1.php');
    $File1 = new File1;
    $File1::file1_register();
}
register_activation_hook(FILE, 'MyActivation');
```

The function file1_register just refuse to work, eventually I would like to run file2_register as well, but at this point, I can't see the error or problem with my code, please help.

Comment: I think you want the [`__FILE__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) magic constant instead of `FILE`. If you had [debugging enabled](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) you would see an error. But this looks to be a pure PHP question to me. Your code works without that `include` and with everything in the same file though instantiating the class only to call it statically is pointless.

Comment: Also, you are misusing the [scope resolution operator (`::`)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php). `$File1` does not hold a classname, but is an instance/object of a class. Hence the arrow operator (`->`) is the appropriate one to use in this case.

Comment: @user31108 , Johannes Pille is referring to the same issue I noted at the end of my comment. I am a little surprised that what you did-- `$File1::file1_register();`-- worked at all, much less worked without so much as a `Notice`.

Comment: Thank you, s_ha_dum, Johannes Pille, the suggestions were great, it did not resolve the problem so I just stuffed everything into one file and call it a day.

Answer (score 3):

You have two options either define you register methods as static and then you can avoid instantiating your classes or even calling the `MyActivation` function ex:

File1.php:

```
Class File1 {
    static function file1_register() {
        //register some short codes;
    }
    static function file1_unregister() {
        //unregister previous short codes;
    }
}
```

File2.php:

```
Class File2 {
    static function file2_register() {
        //create some database tables.
    }
    static function file1_unregister() {
        //delete previous tables.
    }
}
```

MyPlugin.php:

```
include_once dirname( __FILE__ ).'/File1.php';
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( 'File1', 'file1_register' ) );
include_once dirname( __FILE__ ).'/File2.php';
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( 'File2', 'file2_register' ) );
```

**OR** simply change the "Paamayim Nekudotayim" (::) to the arrow operator (->) in your current `MyActivation` function which means replace this line:

```
$File1::file1_register();
```

with this:

```
$File1->file1_register();
```

Comment: Thank you, Bainternet, I tried your codes, but things were not resolved so I just stuffed everything into one file and call it a day.

Comment: care to elaborate "not resolved" the code i posted works in my plugins.